# Crystal report viewer not display after publish

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a problem with Crystal report when I publish my website Crystal report, the viewer doesn't show the report, it shows a blank page.

How to fix it?

Please help me..

on button click code:

```
 protected void btnShowReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        try
        {
            clsFunctions objFunc = new clsFunctions();
            CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = true;
            report.FileName = Server.MapPath(@"~/reports/NoteBalanceSheetRepot.rpt");
            string server = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServer"];
            string user = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportUserID"];
            string password = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportUserPwd"];
            string database = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportDatabase"];
            report.SetDatabaseLogon(user, password, server, database);

            string strSelection = "1=1 ";
            string strTitle = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CompanyName"].ToString();
            string strTitle1 = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppName"].ToString();
            string SelectedDate = ClosingYear.Text.Replace("-","/");
            string ClosingDate = SelectedDate.Insert(3, "0");
            string NextYear = DateTime.ParseExact(ClosingDate.ToString(), "mm/dd/yyyy", null).ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");
            string previousYear = DateTime.ParseExact(ClosingDate.ToString(), "mm/dd/yyyy", null).ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");
            string[] getsp = previousYear.Split('/');
            string dd= getsp[0].ToString().Replace(getsp[0],"07");
            string mm = getsp[1].ToString().Replace(getsp[1], "01");
            int yyyy = Convert.ToInt32(getsp[2]) - 1;
            string Final = mm + "/" + dd + "/" + yyyy;
            report.SetParameterValue("CompanyName", strTitle);
            report.SetParameterValue("AppName", strTitle1);
            report.SetParameterValue("NYear", getsp[2]);
            report.SetParameterValue("PYear", yyyy);
            report.SetParameterValue("nextYear",NextYear );
            report.SetParameterValue("previousYear", Final);
            objECls.FileName = "~/reports/NoteBalanceSheetRepot.rpt";
            objECls.SelectionFormula = strSelection;
            clsFunctions.SaveEntity(ViewState, objECls);
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;

        }
        catch (BusinessLogic.CustomException ex1)
        {
            (new clsFunctions()).SetMessage(ex1.Message, Master);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

.aspx code

```
 <td>
    <asp:Button ID="btnShowReport" runat="server" Text="Preview"  OnClick="btnShowReport_Click"/>
 
 </td></tr>
 <tr>
 <td colspan="4">
      <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" 
            AutoDataBind="true"  Visible="false" 
            ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" />
            <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server" >
                                <Report FileName="reports\NoteBalanceSheetRepot.rpt">
                                </Report>
                            </CR:CrystalReportSource>
```

Comment: Please show your work..

Comment: its work fine on localhost but not show after publish